# How to convert all css links in inline styles using smarty - seo speed optimization

Tags: php, performance, optimization, seo, smarty

I am trying to make my css links inline ( for a speed optimization ). Here is a sample with a pure php:

```
echo '<style>';
foreach ($module_css_files as $css_lib) { 
    include(DIR_FS_ROOT. 'htdocs/css/' . $css_lib);
} //foreach
echo '</style>';
```

But in smarty this idea not work - when I try to

```
{include file="mysite/htdocs/style.css" }
```

each time smarty return white screen no error in php log. If try to include a normal .tpl or small javascript file this is not a problem but if try with css smarty just crashed. Please help!

Comment: Do you spotted an error in the error log?

Comment: Not log, nothing just white screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible explanations:

Depending of your configuration, Smarty may be trying to generate the parsed file at htdocs/css/templates_c. If the folder does not exist or is not writable, that will produce an error

Smarty would try to parse the css as a Smarty template, so i.e.

```
.test {overflow:hidden}
```

would also produce an error. You can try the following:

add {literal} to your css between comments so it doesn't break the css file if you want to call it instead of using it inline:

```
/*{literal}*/
.test {overflow:hidden}
...

/*{/literal}*/
```

or, if you're using smarty 3, you can just make sure that there is at least one space after every opening bracket so smarty doesn't confuses it with a template instruction

```
.test { overflow:hidden}
```

The best option, however, would be to read the css file contents with php and pass them to smarty as a variable, just to avoid the unnecessary processing time it may take to read and parse the css as a template.

Comment: Yes, I did the job this way - read the css file contents with php and pass them to smarty as a variable